# How can we get the value of the item passing only index of that particualar Dropdown list in jquery?

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I have list of items in the Dropdown list. and i want the value from the dropdown list on the basis of Index that is passed..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [eq](http://api.jquery.com/eq) method to select the option at the (zero-based) index, then get it's value (`val()`) or text (`text()`).

```
var item = $('#dropdownlist option').eq(index).val();
```